# Calculating a nearby street to use on streetview

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am facing an unusual problem where I need to calculate the latlong of a position on a map that has streetview imagery, without knowing the actual position.

I know the end destination of my user, but I need to calculate the latlong of a nearby position (approximately 1km away or less, this should be variable) that has streetview imagery and use that as the start destination.

An example would be that I know I need to go to Times Square, but I want to have a start destination that is about 1km away by road. I then need to verify that there is street view imagery for this co-ordinate before I decide that it's the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below recursively doubles the search distance, (up to a maximum of 10000 meters), until a panorama is found.

Sample code:

```
// Global vars
var G = google.maps;
var streetViewService = new G.StreetViewService();

function getNearSVP(latlon,maxDist) {
    streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(latlon, maxDist, function(data, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            return data.location.latLng;
        }
        else{
            if (maxDist < 10000){
                maxDist = maxDist * 2;
                return getNearSVP(latlon, maxDist);
            }
            else {
                alert('StreetView is not available within '+maxDist+' meters of this location');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

[**Live demo here**](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/ac.html)

Comment: This looks like a really elegant solution. Thanks for the demo. I'll test this out once I solve my other problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338256/how-to-update-this-street-view-example-to-maps-api-v3